# Client credentials grant generate tokens for lifetime

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I am creating an API in laravel a using two grants [password, client_credentials] and I want to configure token lifetime for separate for both grants.

If I configure token lifetimes according to [laravel passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-lifetimes) then its set's for both grants.

I need help to configure separate lifetime for both grants.

Answer (score 0):

Create the access token with `$token = $user->createToken('API Access')` and use a query with `DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('id', $token->id)->update([...])` to change the value of 'expires_at' manually.

Apply same on '**oauth_refresh_tokens**' with `->where('access_token_id', $token->id)`

Answer (score 0):

In the boot function of your AuthServiceProvider you can still check the value of grant_type in your request to define different lifetime.

```
if($request["grant_type"] === "client_credentials"){
        // If token is a client_credential we define it to one year
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYear());
    }else{
        // Or we define it to only one hour
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addHour());
    }
```